# Jasper Report : Lines and border are not getting printed in PDF format

Tags: internet-explorer, jasper-reports

When I am printing a jasper report in pdf format it is working properly and all the Lines/borders displaying correctly in browser except IE. In the case of printing in pdf format in IE, it is not working properly. The lines and border of text field is getting missing.

After lots of searching I can not find a good answer.

so please help me out.

Left side from IE and right in PDF (CTRL-P)
[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you opening a pdf file in IE (left picture)? What kind of file opened at IE?

Comment: Left side is Html page from IE(browser screen) and Right side is pdf , which is saved as pdf after selecting print option (CLRT +P)

Comment: If you saved html file from IE as pdf file it is not a JasperReports issue. If you need valid *pdf* you should export report as pdf